# How to get collection of id of radio buttons contained in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want o get a list of all the radio buttons that are contained in a div using javascript or jquery.

eg

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="radio" id="1">
    <input type="radio" id="2">
    <input type="radio" id="3">
     .... //total no of radio buttons are not known
</div>
```

I want an array containing an id of all radio buttons contained in div.

```
arr[0]="1"
arr[1]="2"
arr[2]="3"
...
..
```

Comment: The first example at http://api.jquery.com/map/ does what you are asking for, you just need to change the selector appropriately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var array = new Array();
$('#container input:radio').each(function (index) {
    array[index] = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Comment: This one won't work for several reasons. 1) you don't specify inputs; 2) `$(this)` is an array. To work in your way you need to use `$(this)[0].id`

Comment: Will this work if radios are contained in nested div within #container ?

Answer (score 6):

```
var ids = $('#container :radio').map(function() { return this.id; }).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
var arr= [];
$('#container :radio').each(function(){
 arr.push({ "the_id": this.id, "val":this.value })
});
//right now you have a json like array with ID and value and you can access it by `arr[0].the_id` and `arr[0].val`
```

You can only push the id (without value, so no curly bracket needed) and you can access elements like `arr[0]`